# Issue not display canvas object on sensor change

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, android-mapview

I have develop one map application in which I want to display compass at top -right side of map screen. compass is ready to work and map also but when i put both together its not display compass (I mean its raise issue when I draw compass in dispatch draw of custom mapview class )

it's strange that I have make two canvas object
1. compass by drawing Path(arrow)
2. Text "N"
here on display its display Text however its not display compass.

here is Custom Mapview class for clearity..

```
package com.Espiritos.Home.Map;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView;
import org.mapsforge.core.GeoPoint;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.Espiritos.Utility.AppLog;


/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Class Name: MyMapView
Created By: 704
Created Date:
Modified By: 
Modified Date: 
Purpose: All Listener and Canvas method are introduce in this class for map operation
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public class MyMapView extends MapView 
{   
    private float mfDirection = 0;
    private float[] mfRotateValue;
    private Paint mPntCompass = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private boolean mIsFirstDraw;

    /** ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // LISTENER DEFINITIONS
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

     */
    /** Change listener for mapview*/
    public interface OnChangeListener
    {
        public void onChange(MapView view, GeoPoint newCenter, GeoPoint oldCenter, int newZoom, int oldZoom);
    }
    /** ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MEMBERS
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    private MyMapView mThis;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas amcanvas) {

        super.onDraw(amcanvas);

    }

    private long mlEventsTimeout = 1500;//250L;     // Set this variable to your preferred timeout
    private boolean mIsTouched = false;
    private GeoPoint mLastCenterPosition;
    private int miLastZoomLevel;
    private Timer mChangeDelayTimer = new Timer();
    private MyMapView.OnChangeListener mChangeListener = null;

    private int miOldZoomLevel = -1;
    private OnClusterMapZoomListener onClusterMapZoomListener;

    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: MyMapView(CONSTRUCTORS)
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: Get Context from base and use in operation
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    public MyMapView(Context amcontx)
    {
        super(amcontx);
        init();
    }

    public MyMapView(Context amcontext, AttributeSet amAttrs)
    {
        super(amcontext, amAttrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: init
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: get Mapcenter and Map ZoomLevel
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private void init()
    {
        mThis = this;
        mLastCenterPosition = this.getMapPosition().getMapCenter();
        miLastZoomLevel = this.getMapPosition().getZoomLevel();

        mPntCompass.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPntCompass.setStrokeWidth(4);
        mPntCompass.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        mPntCompass.setTextSize(30);
        mPntCompass.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPntCompass.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));

        mIsFirstDraw = true;
    }


    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: setOnChangeListener
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: Mapview change listener implementation 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    public void setOnChangeListener(MyMapView.OnChangeListener l)
    {
        mChangeListener = l;
    }


    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: onTouchEvent
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: on touch event handling with motionEvent
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {       
        /** Set touch internal*/
        mIsTouched = (ev.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);

        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: computeScroll
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: scroll change counting by this method
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    @Override
    public void computeScroll()
    {
        super.computeScroll();

        /**Check for change*/
        if (isSpanChange() || isZoomChange())
        {
            /** 
             * If computeScroll called before timer counts down 
               we should drop it and 
               start counter over again
             */
            resetMapChangeTimer();
        }
    }

    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: resetMapChangeTimer
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: after scroll it get change the position, it getting new position update
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private void resetMapChangeTimer()
    {
        mChangeDelayTimer.cancel();
        mChangeDelayTimer = new Timer();
        mChangeDelayTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (mChangeListener != null) mChangeListener.onChange(mThis, getMapPosition().getMapCenter(), mLastCenterPosition, getMapPosition().getZoomLevel(), miLastZoomLevel);
                mLastCenterPosition = getMapPosition().getMapCenter();
                miLastZoomLevel = getMapPosition().getZoomLevel();
            }
        }, mlEventsTimeout);
    }


    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: isSpanChange
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: after scroll it get change the position, it getting new position update
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private boolean isSpanChange()
    {
        return !mIsTouched && !getMapPosition().getMapCenter().equals(mLastCenterPosition);
    }


    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: isZoomChange
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: Get current zoom level
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private boolean isZoomChange()
    {
        return (getMapPosition().getZoomLevel() != miLastZoomLevel);
    }

    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: dispatchDraw
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: This method is used to Draw Polygon in map
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        // Notify listener, if not null, that the zoom level changed
        if (getMapPosition().getZoomLevel() != miOldZoomLevel) {
            miOldZoomLevel = getMapPosition().getZoomLevel();
            if (onClusterMapZoomListener != null) {
                onClusterMapZoomListener.onZoomLevelChanged(miOldZoomLevel);
            }
        }



        if (!mIsFirstDraw) 
        {

                Path mPathArrow = new Path();
                mPathArrow.moveTo(0, -50);
                mPathArrow.lineTo(-20, 40);
                mPathArrow.lineTo(0, 30);
                mPathArrow.lineTo(20, 40);
                mPathArrow.close();

                Paint mPntText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                mPntText.setAntiAlias(true);
                mPntText.setTextSize(30);
                mPntText.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                mPntText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

                int miCanvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
                int miCanvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
                int miCenterX = miCanvasWidth / 2;
                int miCenterY = miCanvasHeight / 2;

                canvas.translate(miCanvasWidth-miCanvasWidth/10, miCanvasHeight/10);
                if (mfRotateValue != null) {
                    canvas.rotate(-mfRotateValue[0]);
                }
                canvas.drawPath(mPathArrow, mPntCompass);
                canvas.drawText("N", miCanvasWidth-miCanvasWidth/10, miCanvasHeight/10, mPntText);

        }

    }

    public void updateDirection(float dir,float[] mevent)
    {
        mIsFirstDraw = false;
        mfDirection = dir;
        this.mfRotateValue = mevent;
        Log.e(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "direction"+mfDirection);
        invalidate();
    }




    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: getOnClusterMapZoomListener
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: get Map Zoomlistner implemented
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    public OnClusterMapZoomListener getOnClusterMapZoomListener() 
    {
        return onClusterMapZoomListener;
    }
    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Method Name: setOnClusterMapZoomListener
    Created By: 704
    Created Date:
    Modified By: 
    Modified Date: 
    Purpose: set Map Zoomlistner implemented
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    public void setOnClusterMapZoomListener(
            OnClusterMapZoomListener onClusterMapZoomListener)
    {
        this.onClusterMapZoomListener = onClusterMapZoomListener;
    }



}
```

Note: I have Make demo aaplication for this and its display very well....
2 : Live app that I am run in samsun 10inch tablet its display but in Samsung s3 its not ...

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the issue by changing in Manifest file minSdkversion=3 to 8 and its solve , its amazing that its work,still not know the logic behind that...if you know then let me know why its happen